# How would that be possible to move the Edit button on top of the DetailsView?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, detailsview

I have a DetailsView which is bound to a SqlDataSource. It also has an Edit CommandField which appears on the bottom of the autogenerated rows.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server"  
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="150px" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Caption="System Parameters" CellSpacing="2">           
            <Fields>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True"  />
            </Fields>           
</asp:DetailsView>
```

There are over 50 columns so I wouldn't like to add the bound fields manually.

How would that be possible to move the Edit button on top of the DetailsView (first row)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit unclear, but a possible solution would be to give the edit button a relative position. Then move it to the top by using the top (-) or bottom (+) functions.